# Python change element in array

Tags: python, list

How I can change element in array?
I have this code, but I expected that it would print `[[5,5],[1,4]]`. But it wouldn't. It still prints `[[1,2],[1,4]]`.

```
x = [[1,2], [1,4]]
for element in x:
    if element[1] == 2:
        element = [5,5]
print x
```

Comment: you need to add element to x and remove the one you dont want

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change a list element requires an index.

```
list_object[index] = new_value
```

Using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), you can iterate the list and get a indexes.

```
>>> x = [[1,2], [1,4]]
>>> for i, element in enumerate(x):
...     if element[1] == 2:
...         x[i] = [5,5]
...
>>> x
[[5, 5], [1, 4]]
```